# Convert snippet to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found  [a wonderful article](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=408)

But it uses rails version previous to rails 3.

In particular, this snippet:

```
<%= link_to_remote( "click here",
                   :update => "time_div",
                   :url => { :action => :say_when },
                   :position => "after" ) %>
```

I converted it to this:

```
<%=button_to 'Click',:remote=>true,:update=>"time_div",:position=>"after",:action=>"say_when"%>
```

But, there's something wrong.The entire page is being rendered afresh.
What should be done to make it work as described on that site?

Answer (score 1):

it is not `button_to`, it is `link_to 'Click', :remote => true`. Also you have to add `csrf_meta_tag` in the head tag in the layout for Rails 3. See [link](http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/02/24/rails-3-ujs-and-csrf-meta-tags/)

Comment: I know its link_to.But i want to use a button instead of link.Also, i have the csrf meta tag in my application.html.erb. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
In your layout <%= csrf_meta_tag %> And 
link_to "some action", my_action_path(@post), :remote => true
```

For details Try this link

http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/02/24/rails-3-ujs-and-csrf-meta-tags/

Comment: i have the srf tag in my application.html.erb. But, this is a simple code not involving any resource like post.